# not able to set environment variable using Jenkins batch command line

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, svn

I am working on Jenkins android app automation. I have automated Android version name from manifest file for example version name `1.0.1.45` and set the version name as environment variable. I have `test.bat` file code looks like below.

```
@For /F %%A In ('Powershell -C "[xml]$fC=Get-Content 'AndroidManifest.xml';"^
 "$fC.manifest.versionName"') Do @Set "versionName=%%A"
@Echo %versionName% > name.txt
```

Now I am calling this `test.bat` file from Jenkins under "execute windows batch command" section and it ran but it is not able to set as environment  variable.

Also I am giving svn command under "execute windows batch command" as 
`svn commit -m " updated version %versionName% "`.

In build output it should show update version `1.0.1.25`. but is not taking as a environment  variable. Please can you help me

Comment: The question asked less than a day ago for which I gave, and you have subsequently copied, the code was to create a `versionName` variable. That variable would have been local only to that running script, not set globally for use in future scripts. Are you trying to set a variable outside of the locally running `test.bat` script? BTW, if you only want the script to output to another text file, just use `@Powershell -C "[xml]$fC=GC 'AndroidManifest.xml';$fC.manifest.versionName">"name.txt" 2>Nul`.

Comment: test.bat script is running perfectly in my local system but when i run it from Jenkins console it will not set  as environment variable. how to set the variable globally please can you advise

Comment: If the content of `name.txt` from your posted script reads correctly then the `versionName` variable was set! What I am telling you is that the variable is set only for the benefit and use of `test.bat`. It isn't being set as a variable for use by whatever in the system needs it.

Comment: name.txt i just testing purpose written, Please ignore name.txt file here. Do @Set "versionName=%%A value is set in my local command line but it is not set as a environment variable by using Jenkins 'execute windows batch command line

Comment: can you advise how to set as globally ?

Comment: Write the information in the format `VariableName=VariableValue` to a text file, then use the [EnvInject plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) to read in that information such that `VersionName` would be available to your subsequent build steps. You can output that using the following single line batch file: `@For /F %%A In ('Powershell -C "[xml]$fC=GC 'AndroidManifest.xml';$fC.manifest.versionName" 2^>Nul') Do (@Echo versionName=%%A)>"name.txt"`.

Comment: Thanks, I have given the path of the test.bat file  in EnvInject  Plugin but still it is not reading the value. please can you advise